# Delete all series vs drop measurement

Tags: influxdb

I want to know what's the difference between doing:

```
DROP MEASUREMENT A
```

and

```
DROP SERIES FROM A
```

Since all series and points from A are gone after any of those commands, isn't it just the same?

Comment: Not all ways there is difference between MEASUREMENT and SERIES

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/query_language/database_management/#delete-series-with-delete

> The DELETE query deletes all points from a series in a database. Unlike DROP SERIES, it does not drop the series from the index and it supports time intervals in the WHERE clause.

Better use workaround to fully clean data

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/4275#issuecomment-227219840

Comment: What does `it does not drop the series from the index` mean? What kind of index would be kept if a DELETE query removes the same series as the equivalent DROP?